# Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Int32'. on Blazor/Razor routing parameters

Tags: razor, razor-pages, blazor-server-side, razorengine

I have tried to call a page with /somepage/{Id} where Id is a `[Parameter]` with a int property and the route is called as a string, it shouldn't be impicitly converting string to int? why it it wouldnt work at all? I am expecting it would recognize the parameter as it is...

what should I try to have the routing middleware to recognize the parameter ? even in MVC this works just fine...

the page routing

```
@page "/EditEmployee/{Id}"
```

the link

```
<a href="/EditEmployee/@Employee.EmployeeId" class="btn btn-primary m-1">Edit</a>
```

the parameter in the page

```
    [Parameter]
    public int Id { get; set; }
```

the result is an exception and the page doesnt load

Answer (score 7):

Make it

```
 @page "/EditEmployee/{Id:int}"
```

Comment: As a comment i made it dynamic to stop the exceptions because threw it needed a int to string conversion and then backwards so I assumed that the  int.Parse it didnt work and it threw the exception but I also did what you suggested me

Comment: As a side note: Blazor Hot Reload does not catch this. You'll need a full build cycle.